# Generate Code to represent Tony Stark palladium neck effect

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, canvas

I am trying to create an animated, random generated, palladium toxicity neck effect like the one Tony Stark has on his neck in Ironman 2.

[image: Road rash - Tony Stark palladium toxicity]

My first thought was to create it using SVG's auto generation with a loop to split off as children.

https://codepen.io/tony-hensler/pen/gOPBJWO this didn't go to well at all, I'm not keeping track of the children as they are created, and the lines seem too robotic and ridged.

I have also had a look at altering the code provided on https://codepen.io/Tibixx/pen/MZWRzJ
By altering the following values:-

```
  var cx;
  var cy;
```

but unfortunately this also didn't work out.

My next attempt it to generate a JSON with all of the required coordinates, and then generate a canvas with the lines drawn out.

I defiantly think SVG's are not the was to go with this, so I am going to have a look at drawing it on a canvas.

I maybe overthinking the process with storing the JSON.
How else can I attach this task? Any help with a push in the right direction would be amazing.

Comment: This is a fun tutorial on fractal trees: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fcdNSZ9IzJM Might help you along in the right direction.

Comment: Canvas or SVG doesn't matter, that's just how you render it. The tricky part here is to generate the coordinates for the lines.

Comment: @Terminator-Barbapapa Cheers I'll have a watch.

Comment: @Thomas Yeah, I have created https://codepen.io/tony-hensler/pen/PoZQZOE but I want to take it further and add children's with a proportion of the parents stroke width. It's keeping track of the children.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried changing the Recursive Lightning pattern in such a way that instead of drawing a direct line from (sx,sy) to (cx,cy), you draw two lines (one vertical and one horizontal) ? Essentially you replace the hypotenuse with the two other sides of the right triangle.

I don't have a code example yet but can imagine this working well.

**EDIT:**

[Here](http://prntscr.com/tjnndu) is an example of the result. I worked on the original codepen instead of forking it as well. Do not forget to change both the `draw()` and the `split()` functions.

Comment: @OP there are two places where you have to change `ctx.moveTo(sx,sy); ctx.lineTo(cx,cy);` to `ctx.moveTo(sx,sy); ctx.lineTo(cx,sy); ctx.lineTo(cx,cy);`. I don't want to create an account just to fork this one codepen.

Comment: Amazing that worked like a charm.I have created a JSFiddle of the results, would love to know how get the initial line to start from the left and move right if thats easy to do? - https://jsfiddle.net/zaqog3b2/